# Power BI Dax to Calculate the average in 3 periods

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two below tables in Dim_Date the Period doesn't correspond to exact months and first I calculated a measure to Divide the count of records per region by NumofWeeks.

The Num of the week is always the same in the same period.

Table1

| Region | Subregion | DataID | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| North Central | Missouri | 12042022 | 123000 |
| North Central | Minnesota | 12052022 | 170000 |
| North Central | North Dakota | 10042022 | 234000 |
| Northeast | New York | 08042022 | 500000 |
| Northeast | New Jersey | 12052022 | 578000 |
| Southwest | Nevada | 12032022 | 679000 |
| Southwest | Arizona | 10032022 | 654000 |

DimDate

| DataID | Period | NumofWeeks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12052022 | 2022_05 | 5 |
| 10042022 | 2022_04 | 4 |
| 12042022 | 2022_04 | 4 |
| 12052022 | 2022_05 | 5 |
| 08042022 | 2022_04 | 4 |
| 12032022 | 2022_03 | 4 |
| 10032022 | 2022_03 | 4 |

```
Divide per region week =
VAR TotalCountPerRegion = COUNT(Table1[Region])
VAR tblNumOfWeeksInPeriod=
SUMMARIZE(
DimDate
,DimDate[Period]
,DimDate[NumofWeeks]
)

VAR SuMOfWeeksInPeriod = SUMX(tblNumOfWeeksInPeriod,DimDate[NumofWeeks])

RETURN
MROUND(
DIVIDE(
TotalCountPerRegion
,SuMOfWeeksInPeriod
)
,1
)
```

With the formula, I got the following table

| Period | Divide per region week |
| --- | --- |
| 2021_04 | 17 |
| 2021_05 | 15 |
| 2021_06 | 9 |
| 2021_07 | 16 |
| 2021_08 | 20 |
| 2021_09 | 21 |
| 2021_10 | 17 |
| 2021_11 | 19 |
| 2021_12 | 20 |
| 2022_01 | 27 |

I want a new formula to calculate the average of the period with 2 following periods
Example

Average 2021_04 = 2021_04 + 2021_05 + 2021_06 = (17+15+9)/3

Average 2021_05 = 2021_05 + 2021_06 + 2021_07 = (15+9+16)/3

and so on.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Please, let me know if you are still interested in solving the case

Comment: Hi, I am still looking for a solution maybe my question is not clear...  I will add more details ...

Comment: Ok. So I will wait for details. I'm on trip till thursday, so I will be able to look throw the details of Friday or weekend. Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

I accepted this solution thank you very much ...

```bash
[M 3-Period Rolling Avg] =
// Set the number of periods to calculate
// the average over.
var PeriodCount = 3
// First, get the last visible period.
var LastPeriodSeqno = MAX( Dim_Date[PeriodSeqno] )
// Then, get the periods over which to calc.
var PeriodsToAverageOver =
    CALCULATETABLE(
        DISTINCT( Dim_Date[PeriodSeqno] ),
        // Here's the place where you use the fact that
        // all the periods are consecutively numbered.
        // In fact, the counting does not have to start
        // at 1 but it has to increment by 1.
        Dim_Date[PeriodSeqno] <= LastPeriodSeqno,
        Dim_Date[PeriodSeqno] > LastPeriodSeqno - PeriodCount,
        REMOVEFILTERS( Dim_Date )
    )
// We need to make sure that there are indeed
// PeriodCount periods in the set. Otherwise,
// the average will not be correct. This could happen
// if we were too close to the beginning of the calendar.
var ShouldCalculate =
    COUNTROWS( PeriodsToAverageOver ) = PeriodCount
var Result =
    if( ShouldCalculate,
        CALCULATE(
            AVERAGEX(
                PeriodsToAverageOver,
                [M]
            ),
            REMOVEFILTERS( Dim_Date )
        )
    )
return
    Result
```

Answer (score 0):

My calendar is different for example the periods are like a financial calendar the period

- 2021_04 - Starts on 05/04/2021 and finishes on 02/05/2021
- 2021_05 - Starts on 03/05/2021 and finishes on 30/05/2021
- 2021_06 - Starts on 31/05/2021 and finishes on 04/07/2021

I want to calculate

```bash
Divide per region week =
VAR TotalCountPerRegion = COUNT(Table1[Region])
VAR tblNumOfWeeksInPeriod=
SUMMARIZE(
DimDate
,DimDate[Period]
,DimDate[NumofWeeks]
)

VAR SuMOfWeeksInPeriod = SUMX(tblNumOfWeeksInPeriod,DimDate[NumofWeeks])

RETURN
MROUND(
DIVIDE(
TotalCountPerRegion
,SuMOfWeeksInPeriod
)
,1
)
```

Rolling 3 periods if we start in 2021_04  I have

- 2021_06 = Average(2021_06+2021_05+2021_04)
- 2021_07 = Average(2021_07+2021_06+2021_05)
- 2021_08 = Average(2021_08+2021_07+2021_06)
  and so on

I need to incorporate the formula above because the average is the sum of the formula for 3 periods.

Thanks in advance